# How Do I Import a Local Python File With Relative Paths

Tags: python, python-import

I have been working at this for a while, but I have not been making a ton of progress, and I want to know how to import a python file into another, and with the help of a couple websites and debugging I have gotten to this code: `import (__file__ + "\Assets\Minigames\minigame1")`. I am getting this error in VSCode: *Expected module namePylance Statements must be separated by newlines or semicolonsPylance*

Comment: Please share you file structure so that we can help.

Comment: @bichanna Here it is: https://imgur.com/a/KOUs9fk